# Можно ли отследить появление кнопок по тексту и две из трёх скрыть?

Tags: javascript

На странице появляются одновременно 3 кнопки, они могут появлятся в разном порядке. В кнопках имееется разный текст. Это три ответа на один какой-нибудь вопрос. Возможно ли как-нибудь удалить только две кнопки? Можно ли как-то отследить первые буквы в кнопке по алфавилу и удалить их, а оставить только одну кнопку у которой текст начинается на букву, которая в алфавите стоит позже? Реально ли такое?

```
<div class="couple-flex-row couple-flex-center couple-relation-card--answers-3">  
            <button class="js-couple-relation-card--answers--button couple-relation-card--answers--button" data-id="1079617332"> Зомби </button>
        
            <button class="js-couple-relation-card--answers--button couple-relation-card--answers--button" data-id="928946082">  Летающие машины </button>
        
            <button class="js-couple-relation-card--answers--button couple-relation-card--answers--button" data-id="2924987928"> Каменный век </button>        
    
</div>
```

Знаю что можно сортировать по алфавиту, но как применить на практике для того, что-бы скрыть кнопки не знаю.

```
const string = "эцтшвбкюуязлдыъгаьёмижрщохпенфйсч"
const compare = (new Intl.Collator('ru')).compare

function sortAndReverse(string, reverse = false) {
  return string.split('')
    .sort((a, b) => ((reverse ? -1 : 1) * compare(a, b)))
    .join('')
} 

console.log(sortAndReverse(string))
```

Comment: Возможно. Можно. Реально.

Comment: Как? Жду ответ)))

Comment: Удалить кнопки можно с помощью removeChild. Получить буквы из кнопок можно с помощью innerText или innerHtml. С сортировкой по алфавиту вы уже разобрались

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно ли как-то отследить первые буквы в кнопке по алфавилу и удалить их, а оставить только одну кнопку у которой текст начинается на букву, которая в алфавите стоит позже? Реально!

```js
removeFirst()

function removeFirst() {
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('.buttons')

    Array.from(wrapper.children)
        .sort((a, b) => {
            a = a.textContent.trim().toLowerCase()
            b = b.textContent.trim().toLowerCase()

            if (a > b) return -1
            else if (a < b) return 1
            else return 0
        })
        .filter((el, idx) => idx !== 0)
        .forEach(el => el.remove())
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">  
    <button class="js-couple-relation-card--answers--button couple-relation-card--answers--button" data-id="1079617332">Зомби</button>
    <button class="js-couple-relation-card--answers--button couple-relation-card--answers--button" data-id="928946082">Летающие машины</button>
    <button class="js-couple-relation-card--answers--button couple-relation-card--answers--button" data-id="2924987928">Каменный век</button>        
</div>
```

Comment: Meth0d, спасибо! Это почти  то что надо. Работает с кнопки на ура. Но у меня была задумка не с кнопки удалять, а что-бы при появлении этих 3-х кнопок само удалялось. Понимаю, что нужен для этого MutationObserver.  Сам попытался, но как обычно потерпел фиаско.  Можно попросить внедрить, его в MutationObserver ибо мне это явно  не подсилу)

Comment: Вам не нужен `MutationObserver`. Просто запустить функцию при инициализации страницы. Поправил код. Если было полезно, отметьте ответ как правильный.

Comment: Meth0d, не, Mutation observer был необходим. Я запускаю код через расширение в браузере.  Как вы переделали сейчас код, так сразу и наблюдатель мой заработал. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Meth0d, добрый день! Столкнулся  у себя проблемой, которую,  подумав понял, что можно устранить, если будет удалятся кнопки с текстом наоборот от конца алфавита. Что нужно поменять в коде Код вроде малюсенький, но мне это не под силу.

Comment: Meth0d, второй вариант решения это что-бы этот код не реагировал на слова ДА и НЕТ. Просто у меня я с помощью моего кода уже удаляется кнопка со словом  НЕТ, а ваш код удаляет мне ещё и Да,  Да, стоит по алфавиту раньше.